# Google Webmaster Tools not showing search analytics after CDN

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console

I enabled CloudFront CDN for js, css and images on my Wordpress + Woocommerce website on November 12. Everything was working as expected and speed increased by 200%.

Today I logged into Google Analytics and when clicking on Search Engine Optimization/Queries I see 0 queries from November 12 onwards. After double checking in Webmaster Tools under Search Traffic/Search Analytics the date range ends at November 12 as well.

Is there a 7 day delay in reporting these statistics or could implementing a CDN inadvertently break things related to search indexing and queries?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems I might have found an answer. There is apparently a bug with Google affecting everyone, not just me. See here: http://searchengineland.com/google-search-console-search-analytics-data-delayed-but-google-is-working-on-a-fix-236374

Do other people experience this as well at the moment?